# Is there a specific term for this SDE?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I know that $dX_t = aX_tdt + bX_tdW_t$ is the equation for the dynamics of the price of stock in the Black scholes options according to wikipedia.

Is there this equation something common?

$$dX_t = aX_tdt + bdW_t$$  where the solution is $X_t$ given that $X_0 = x$?

I am very new to studying SDEs and having a hard time understanding a lot of things. I am currently trying to solve this to prepare for a future class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special case of an [Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process#Representation_via_a_stochastic_differential_equation) with $\mu=0$: $$dX_t = \theta(\mu - X_t)dt + \sigma dW_t\,\,. $$ Also using your notation $\theta=-a$ and $\sigma=b$.

**Note:** this only works (according to the Wikipedia definition) if $a<0$, since to be an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process one requires that $\theta > 0$.

However, other definitions (see for example [here](https://mediatum.ub.tum.de/doc/1072652/1072652.pdf)) allow for that parameter to be non-positive (the only requirement for the parameter $\gamma=\theta$ given in that paper is that $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$).

Likewise, Wikipedia says $\sigma >0$ while Maller et al says that $\sigma \ge 0$. So without restrictions on $b = \sigma$, technically your process is a generalization of the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Even if I can't solve it at the moment I would like to read more about it.

Comment: @mathematician123493 It is definitely a very important and common process (at least to physicists) so I think you will benefit from doing so. I also find SDEs to be difficult/not straightforward.

Comment: I thought this was financial mathematics related? This is a question from a book we will be using next semester so I just assumed it was stock related...

Comment: @mathematician123493 It has applications to that too. The subject exists in and of itself -- the beauty of it is that you can apply it to anything with the proper structure.

Comment: so is the answer to this just by substituting in $x_t = x_te^{at}$  given my constants  and then just integrating it which leads to the solution of $x_t = x_0*e^{-at} +  be^{at}\int_0^t{e^{as}dW_s}$ ?

Comment: @mathematician123493 That sounds right, although I'm not great at this myself, so I'm not sure. The Wikipedia page seems to cover how to solve the equation -- in any case, you might benefit from asking how to solve it as a separate/new question on Math.SE

Comment: I figured it out! There was a part on the wikipedia page that I wasn't 100% sure about but http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2061128/solving-this-sde-dx-t-ax-tdt-bdw-t-x-0-x-to-find-ex-t2/2061138?noredirect=1#comment4231052_2061138, Behrouz does a great job explaining the steps.