# Having trouble understanding what brownian bridge really is

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

In here, [Solving this SDE $dX_t = aX_tdt + bdW_t$, $X_0 = x$ to find $E[X_t^2]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2061128/solving-this-sde-dx-t-ax-tdt-bdw-t-x-0-x-to-find-ex-t2/2061138?noredirect=1#comment4231052_2061138)

I learned how to find the solution to everything analytically.

However, I want to approximate it now using the Brownian Bridge.

I found this code,from here:https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~rgranero/files/ingles.pdf

```
function [B,P,t1]=puentebrowniano(N,M)
%This function approach M trajectories of the brownian bridge
%in then [0,1] interval with step 1/N
t1=0:1/N:1;
B=zeros(N+1,M);
P=B;
for j=1:M
 for i=1:N
    B(i+1,j)=B(i,j)+normrnd(0,sqrt(1/N)); %the brownian motion
    % incrementsare normals with zero mean and standard
    %deviation (1/N)^(1/2)
    P(i,j)=B(i,j)-t1(i)*B(end,j);%we know P(t)=B(t)-t(B(T))
    end
end
```

How does this interpolate the SDE?

Comment: Indeed the Brownian bridge $(P_t)_{0\leqslant t\leqslant1}$ from $P_0=0$ to $P_1=0$ in time $1$ can be defined as $P_t=B_t-tB_1$, where $(B_t)_{0\leqslant t\leqslant1}$ is a standard Brownian motion. What is unclear though, in the code you reproduce, is how one can simulate $P(i)$ the value of the Brownian bridge at time $i/N$ without first computing $B(\text{end})$ the value of the corresponding Brownian motion at time $1$. Note also that $dX=aXdt+bdW$ is definitely not solved by a Brownian bridge.

Comment: I believe it's possible with stratified sampling? I'm just not really sure how to use these approximation methods.

Comment: This is much simpler than you make it... See below.

Answer (score 3):

Your four (!) recent questions on exactly the same subject seem to indicate you are basically lost trying to apply what you call stratified sampling, which might be quite irrelevant.

To simulate solutions of the stochastic differential equation $dX_t=aX_tdt+bdW_t$ on the time interval $[0,1]$, starting from $X_0=x$, simply use the following:

```
function [W,X]=solvingsde(N,M,a,b,x)
% This function simulates M trajectories of a Brownian
% motion W and of the solution X of the SDE dX=aXdt+bdW 
% on [0,1] starting from X_0=x with step 1/N
W=zeros(N+1,M);
X=W;
for j=1:M
 X(1,j)=x 
 for i=1:N
    W(i+1,j)=W(i,j)+normrnd(0,sqrt(1/N));
    X(i+1,j)=X(i,j)+a*X(i,j)*(1/N)+b*(W(i+1,j)-W(i,j)); 
 end
end
```

Comment: ah.... I'm just new to this and I guess I'll just figure out the stratified sampling next semester when I take the class. I've been up all night trying to get this so I'm fried. I think I understand this... it was A LOT simpler than I've been making it out to be thanks!